# How to upload media files in app/code/Vendor/Module/web/images directory?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, image-upload, media-images

How can I upload media files inside the "app/code/Vendor/Module/web/images" directory? I am creating a custom form page on the admin page. In that form, I have created an image uploader component. Now I need to store the uploaded images inside the "app/code/Vendor/Module/web/images" directory.

This is my custom Model uploader which is I copied from `"Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader"`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\File\Uploader;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\File\Name;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Jason File Uploader
 */
class FileUploader
{
    /**
     * @var Database
     */
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

    /**
     * @var WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @var UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseTmpPath;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $basePath;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $allowedExtensions;

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $allowedMimeTypes;

    /**
     * @var Name
     */
    private $fileNameLookup;

    private $directoryKey;

    /**
     * ImageUploader constructor.
     *
     * @param Database $coreFileStorageDatabase
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     * @param string $basePath
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     * @param string[] $allowedMimeTypes
     * @param Name|null $fileNameLookup
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        $baseTmpPath,
        $basePath,
        $allowedExtensions,
        $allowedMimeTypes = [],
        Name $fileNameLookup = null
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        //$this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        //Here I tried to get my custom directory (app/code/Vendor/Module/web/images) instead of (DirectoryList::MEDIA)
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite('app/code/Vendor/Module/web/images');
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
        $this->allowedMimeTypes = $allowedMimeTypes;
        $this->fileNameLookup = $fileNameLookup ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Name::class);
    }

    /**
     * Set base tmp path
     *
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Set base path
     *
     * @param string $basePath
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowed extensions
     *
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base tmp path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {
        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve allowed extensions
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $imageName
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for moving and move it
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     * @param bool $returnRelativePath
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName, $returnRelativePath = false)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();

        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath(
            $basePath,
            $this->fileNameLookup->getNewFileName(
                $this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath(
                    $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName)
                )
            )
        );
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);

        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).'), $e);
        }

        return $returnRelativePath ? $baseImagePath : $imageName;
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for saving and save it to tmp dir
     *
     * @param string $fileId
     * @return string[]
     *
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();

        /** @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader $uploader */
        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        if (!$uploader->checkMimeType($this->allowedMimeTypes)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('File validation failed.'));
        }
        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));
        unset($result['path']);

        if (!$result) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('File can not be saved to the destination folder.'));
        }

        /**
         * Workaround for prototype 1.7 methods "isJSON", "evalJSON" on Windows OS
         */
        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];

        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).'),
                    $e
                );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

but the above code throwing error:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): Unknown directory
> type: 'app/code/Vendor/Module/web/images'

I have looked into the "Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryLists" class, which provides only a small amount of directories to upload the media files. In that class "app/code" directory was not found.

If anyone is aware of this please suggest me a solution to achieve my requirement. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Upload image at app/code folder is not good idea

Comment: @Amit Bera Yes, thanks for your suggestion, but my requirement is to upload the static images dynamically from the admin panel. I mean client wants to upload the static images dynamically from the admin panel. The static images should be placed into the "app/code/Vendor/Module/web/Images" directory. That's what I am trying. If you have any other suggestions to achieve this requirement please let me know.

Comment: I think that you should have some placeholder images on your module web/images, uploaded by you via FTP, and then if they want custom images uploaded from backend why not save/upload them inside the pub/media folder (Since that's gonna be custom for any other business that use the module)?

Comment: @SiranjeeviKS - even if those images are static you should add them to the pub folder. even the Top Magento plugin vendors do that as it's the correct approach. Create ur plugin folder name inside the pub and add ur images to keep it separate

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed creating a new function as below and use that?

```
/**
         * Retrieve Custom path
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getCustomPath()
        {
            return $this->basePath.”app/code/Vendor/Module/web/images/”;
        }
```